# Avoid duplicating data (in stores and components) in React Flux app?

Tags: reactjs, components, store, flux

I'm starting a project that will be based on Flux, but I noticed something that's bothering me.

Let say I have list of games, so I have `Games` store and a component - `HomepageGames` that listens to that store.

So, when the app loads - it'll pull the games from the server and will save them in the store, and then the React component will put them in it's state as well. So I'll have the games in two places.

But ... the games are a lot ... hundreds.

Also - I have list of URLs that I'm pulling and building two navigations - header and footer. So I'll have the URLs on three places - the `Navigation` store and the two navigation React components.

And the links also can be several hundreds ...

So, how do I avoid this memory bloating ... ? ... or I'll just have to reconcile?

Answer (score 0):

You are not really duplicating the list of games from Store if you are getting the list from Store. With Javascript, by default, you will get a reference for this list in your component.

So, if you will do this in `HomepageGames`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   this.setState({
       games: GameStore.getAllGames()
   });
}
```

You will still have only one list of games in the memory.

Your component have a reference for the list in the `GamesStore`. Try to add some game in this list in your component and you will see your list in the Store be changed too.

In the most of the cases, this is a undesirable behavior. Many people use libs like `Immutable` to avoid this reference. But for you, this seems a good idea.